# Percent coverage of a polygon in a raster grid

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.3, land-cover, density

I have a wooded area polygon and a study area grid of cells with 300m resolution.

I would like to calculate a raster which shows the amount of each grid cell covered by the polygon. The density per km2 would also work, rather than just a binary 1 (has woods), 0 (does not).

Comment: I made some edits to try to make your question a bit clearer - feel free to revert the edits if I got it wrong

Comment: Convert grid to points, points to grid using pointid. Grid to raster, raster to polygon. Intersect with forest, summarise  area per polygonid. Transfer results to polygons, calculate fraction. Polygons to raster

Answer (score 2):

- Convert grid to points
- points to grid using pointID
- raster to polygon, will produce square polygons with unique name
- Intersect with forest
- summarise area per polygon id
- transfer results to polygons by using attribute join
- calculate fraction of total polygon area
- convert polygons to raster

Density per square kilometre is nonsense, unless you define it as ha/km2 or similar. In this case it can be done in raster calculator, using cell size of your grid